# Address Book - "Add New Address" button issue for Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, customer-address

I have issue in Address Book when "Add New Address"
Steps to reproduce:

```
Go to "My Account" page
Navigate to "Address Book"
Click "Add New Address" button
```

Expected result

```
On "Add New Address" button click should prompt a new form to create an additional address
```

also I have discovered that the "Delete Address" button that shows after you have successfully added an additional address to your address book has an href="#" and therefore doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve "Add New Address" button issue replace below code at line no 91:

```
<button type="button" role="add-address" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add New Address')) ?>" class="action primary add"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add New Address')) ?></span></button>
```

with below code

```
<a class="action primary add" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('customer/address/new'); ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add New Address') ?></span></a>
```

To solve "Delete Address" link issue replace below code at line no 78:

```
href="#"
```

with below code

```
href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('customer/address/delete', ['id' => $_address->getId()]) ?>"
```

Now, we need to make some changes in below controller file:

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Address/Delete.php
>   So we need to override controller by creating new module, please refer this link->[How to override](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-controller-override-tutorial/)

On line no 18 from above controller file we need to comment/remove below code:

```
&& $this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())
```

Both issues solved.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone interested I had the same issue with my add new address button doesn't work anymore.
The reason was because I changed the main layout class. (called by x-magento-init)

I fixed it by, copying

```
module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/book.phtml
```

to

```
design/frontend/VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Customer/templates/address/book.phtml
```

at the very bottom of the file change

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    ".page-main": {
        "address": {
            "deleteAddress": "li.item a[role='delete-address']",
            "deleteUrlPrefix": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getDeleteUrl())) ?>id/",
            "addAddress": "button[role='add-address']",
            "addAddressLocation": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getAddAddressUrl())) ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

by

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    ".class-of-your-parent-container": {
        "address": {
            "deleteAddress": "li.item a[role='delete-address']",
            "deleteUrlPrefix": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getDeleteUrl())) ?>id/",
            "addAddress": "button[role='add-address']",
            "addAddressLocation": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getAddAddressUrl())) ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

You add new address button should work now